# How to use Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions

I am a developer with very little knowledge about Firebase Cloud Functions and programming in general. I followed the 'Get started' guide on the 'Firebase Cloud Functions' and have got to this point:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1M5TK.jpg

Now, where should I do all the Node.js coding work? Also, what is the index.js folder and where can I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `firebase init functions` will have created the project files and index.js file + other files and directories as specified in the guide. You should run the init functions command in a directory that you make specifically for the project, not your home directory of `\Users\Arjun Ram`. I would recommend you do the following:

```
md FirebaseProject
cd FirebaseProject
firebase init functions
dir
```

This will create a folder for your project, `cd` into the folder, initialize the firebase project in the folder, and then list the contents of the folder to show you the files the command created. When you do `dir`, you should see a `firebase.json` and a `functions/` directory which contains the `index.js`. You can then continue to proceed with the Getting Started guide.